# Конфигурация mysite.sock

Tags: django, nginx, сокет, vps, uwsgi

Приветствую.
Настраиваю Django-сайт на VPS. Делаю по [инструкции](https://habrahabr.ru/post/226419/)
Но вот в статье начинают говорить о использовании mysite.sock, а у меня такого нет и откуда он берется тоже никакой информации, даже в интернете не нашел.
Может кто сталкивался и знает о чем речь ? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это socket, который создаёт uwsgi для nginx. В конфиге nginx вы должны указать путь до этого файла (не забудьте про права на сам сокет). Сам же сокет создаётся и указывается в mysite_uwsgi.ini (исходя из статьи). То есть в mysite_uwsgi.ini вы указываете, где создать сокет,а  потом в конфиге nginx прописываете его месторасположение. 
Если всё будет правильно, то при запуске uwsgi и nginx, первый создаст сокет, второй будет пулять в него запросы, а первый будет их посылать на Django проект.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Сразу более понятно стало происходящее. Действительно, сокет создается сам, при запуске uwsgi. И вот пока писал этот комментарий, сайт поднялся !)) В общем я сглупил и сам создал сокет, указал на него nginx`у и uwsgi, один раз поменял права, что-то там еще разбирался, перезапускал, а права то я менял на тот старый сокет. А при остановки uwsgi, сокет удаляется, а потом создается новый с дефолтными правами. В общем спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: И еще, похоже пользователь под которым я конфигурировал не находится в нужной группе или вроде того, пока разбираюсь, в общем ему не хватало прав 664, потому еще все заработало, что я указал ему 666 на сокет.

Answer (score 1):

судя по названию файла и по контексту вопроса, речь идёт о [*unix domain socket* (*uds*)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0_UNIX).

служит он для межпроцессного взаимодействия, и в вашем случае надо всего лишь указать обоим процессам (*nginx* и *что-то там на питоне*) одно и то же имя.

например, `/var/run/mysite.sock`

создавать самому этот файл «[особого типа](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_file_types#Socket)», как правило, не требуется: он создаётся одним из взаимодействующих процессов (в вашем случае — «чем-то там на питоне») самостоятельно при его запуске.

---

подробнее про *uds* можно прочитать в соответствующей man-странице:

```
$ man 7 unix
```